# SQL reference to current row

Tags: sql, count

Hello is it possible to reference in SQL to only the current row?

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT MONTH(Date) as Date, COUNT(Id) as Bets, COUNT(Status) as Won, FROM Bets
GROUP BY Datum
```

And now I want to COUNT all won bets in their months.

It should look like this:

```
Month | Bets | Won

1     | 1    | 0

11    | 4    | 2

12    | 2    | 1
```

Now it looks like this:

```
Month | Bets | Won

1     | 1    | 1

11    | 4    | 4

12    | 2    | 2
```

How can I do now add a condition to the Count(Status) clause or handle this issue otherwise?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I have 2 Tables:

**Bets:**

```
Id : int (Primary Key)

Date : date

Status : int (Foreign Key)
```

**Status:**

```
Id : int (Primary Key)

Status : varchar
```

In the tables are a few more but unrelevant columns.

Won should be the count Amount of all bets where the status is like 1.

Status:

1 - Won

2 - Lost

3 - Open

Comment: If `status` is a 0/1 indicator, use `sum()` not `count()`.

Comment: In SQL there is no such thing as "current" row. SQL is set-based, it is not a procedural language which evaluates row-by-row

Comment: Please take a look on my edited Question and sorry for the unclear Question. Hope its better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for conditional aggregation.  I think I understand how you are thinking about this.  So, the answer is that you use `case`:

```
SELECT MONTH(Date) as Date, COUNT(Id) as Bets,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Won
FROM Bets
GROUP BY MONTH(Date);
```

The `case` is doing the conditions "within" a row (all the columns are from the same row).  Note when aggregating by month, you should also usually aggregate by year.

As a note:  the above is ANSI standard SQL and supported by basically all databases.  There are shortcuts in some databases.  For instance Postgres supports the `FILTER` clause which is closer to what you are asking.

Comment: Please take a look on my edited Question and sorry for the unclear Question. Hope its better now.

Comment: @Gohan . . . I think this addresses your modified question.